# Displaying Rendering errors in android studio while using new fonts

Tags: java, android

I've added new font "Roboto Light" in Android Studio 3 and it looks fine during runtime.

However, Android Studio shows rendering error all the time.

Render problem Asset not found: @font/roboto_light

Comment: Rebuild your project

Comment: How to rebuild the existing project

Answer (score 0):

In your android studio >> Navigate to top build menu >> Select Rebuild

[image]